# Firestore client listeners messaging guarantees?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, messaging, firebase-admin

I see that [Cloud Firestore Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#limitations_and_guarantees) provide at-least-once messaging guarantees, but what about the  [snapshot listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#java_1) that are built into the Firestore client libraries (in particular, the Java library)? Do they provide the same messaging guarantees, or is it weaker? I'm struggling to find definitive information on this.

My goal is to have a backend service listening to a Firestore collection. Using the `onShapshot` listeners seems simpler than wiring up a Cloud Function to trigger sending to a PubSub topic, etc.

Comment: I haven't also been able to find any docs about guarantees, but I believe you could just adapt your application with the proper [error handling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#handle_listen_errors).

Comment: Notice that the listener will not receive any more events after the failure, but you could [detach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61423819/how-to-detach-onsnapshot-listener-cloud-firestore) it within your error handling logic and then attach it again.

Comment: Finally, I can see onSnapshot listeners listening to a collection as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48606611/firestore-listen-to-update-on-the-entire-collection) but notice that Firestore triggers can't point to a specific collection per se, but rather use wildcards to point to all the [documents within a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

The snapshot listeners only read documents once they are updated so the expected functionality is one read per change. However, a snapshot listener may read more than once in the [following situation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#listens):

> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for
> example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as
> if you had issued a brand-new query.

Comment: My question has more to do with the messaging guarantees. For instance if I were to deploy a Firebase Cloud Function that triggers off of a document update, I'm guaranteed that my function will trigger on all document updates at least once. Is the same guarantees present when using the snapshot listeners from the client APIs?

Comment: I tried to find any information is snapshop listeners provide any guarantees an it seems that, this is key-feature for Cloud Firestore Triggers only.